# What is the default module name for Ethernet Network Card in YaST?

Tags: drivers, ethernet

I looked on the Internet with no luck.
I know the default module for Wi-Fi is SSB, but what is it for Ethernet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either
yast lan

or (GUI)
yast2 lan